# How to efficiently test in-app subscription for Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an app that i need to test a specific flow when a user manages to successfully subscribe using In-app billing.

The problem is, once I do manage to subscribe for the first time and i need to test the flow again, it's almost impossible to do.

Sadly in order to be able to test again, first I have to cancel my test order from Play Console and issue a refund, then wait many hours for Google servers to really unsubscribe me so I can test again. Now imagine I need to debug this flow like 10 times!

I know this questions has been raised before, but there were no good answers. I was also wondering maybe there are new solutions Today for this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Register https://github.com/NYTimes/Register

It is a developer library/app designed to test in app billing. 
In particular, once your app is using Register, you can purchase a subscription, reset the subscription in the Register app, and re-purchase the subscription.